# Yum update without upgrading CentOS

Tags: centos, yum, centos6.5

Is there a manner in which we can yum update and pull the latest packages but not end up updating CentOS itself?

I know we can alter yum.conf and exclude certain packages and even repos, but if that were the right place, what would I be excluding?

In specific, I'm trying to stop my CentOS 6.5 from upgrading to 6.6

Thanks

Comment: This doesn't appear to make any sense. What is the reason behind it?

Comment: Why? If you need to keep specific packages at specific versions, configure yum to handle this - what's about the version number?

Comment: It is not very clear, what do you want exactly? If you just don't want the updates, don't run `yum update`... or you want to download and apply only *some* updates? Which ones?

Comment: I have software that for some reason breaks whenever the version number changes.  Stupid, I could not agree more, but that's what it is.  Also, the software is not supported on any version of CentOS after 6.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to achieve this is to find a repository which has a CentOS 6.5-specific repository, and alter your configs in /etc/yum.repos.d/* to specifically use this repo (essentially hard-coding the values for the base arch and release version).

It is worth noting, however, that point releases which are not current are not officially supported (old major releases are, to an extent, but point releases are not).

Comment: Cheers.  Between yourself and @Brian I think I'll be doing this.  Mind you, I have no idea why the developer wrote their application in such a manner that it breaks whenever the system version changes from 6.5 to anything else.

Answer (score 1):

What you want does not exist.

Old point releases are not supported so there are no latest packages to pull.

Think of them more as a point in time snapshot of the latest packages for a given release (4.x, 5.x, 6.x, 7.x etc).

The FAQ entry for [What is the versioning/release scheme of CentOS and how does it compare to the upstream vendor?](http://wiki.centos.org/FAQ/General#head-6e2c3746ec45ac3142917466760321e868f43c0e) provides an explanation of what the point releases are.